# How does this Angular JS code snippet work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, hoisting

Why does following snippet work in Angular JS?

```
var app = angular.module('store',[]); 



(function(){
    app.controller('StoreController',function(){
        this.blabla = student;
    });
})();

var student = 
{
    name:"Abc Def",
    rollNumber:12,
    isBrilliant: true,
    isMale:false,
    isFemale: false,
    istest:true
};
```

Even though `student` comes after the function where it's being used and `student` is not hoisted still why does the above function work?

But in contrast to the above example, this one:

```
(function(){
        console.log("Name is :"+student);
    })();

    var student = {
        name:"xyz"
    };
```

Shows `student` as `undefined` means it wasn't hoisted.

Comment: `this.blabla = student;` isn't executed until Angular instantiates the controller, which would happen after you defined student.

Comment: Its is because angular uses a digest cycle and keep on updating the value of $scope and others .... So it repeatedly checks and update $scope with newer values

Comment: Checkout [this](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) article for the 2nd point.It's **IIFE**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.controller` registers a controller function but doesn't execute it right away - it enqueues it for a later phase. Then, `student` variable is assigned an object.

That controller function, however, is a closure over `student` variable - in other words, it has access to it at run-time. [Read more about closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). And so, when it does finally execute, `student` variable is defined.

In contrast, the second example's `console.log`, whether it is enclosed in immediately-invoked function expression or not, executes ***before*** `student` variable is assigned, and so it is `undefined`.

Answer (score 5):

There is a subtle difference between the first example and the second example.  In the first example, there are **two** function blocks, in the second, there is only one.

Both examples are invoked immediately, but where the second function tries immediately to access the outer variable, which hasn't been defined yet, the first merely executes a function to register the controller (and thus, does not execute the contents of the controller function).

By the time the angular framework invokes the controller's constructor function, the outer variable has been defined, and is part of the closure environment.

Comment: It's not because it's a global variable - it's because it's a variable within a function closure.

Comment: true, I'll try to clean that up a bit.